# Content xml is not getting created for Basic activity

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1.4

While creating any activity(other than empty) in android studio it is creating only activity xml, using Android Studio 3.1.4, Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating Basic Activity?

Comment: @UmangBurman yes i tried it, but still same

Comment: Do you have the latest SDK and all the tools installed.. I just created a project on MAC and there is no such thing. :(

Comment: @UmangBurman added the SDK tools image available in my android studio is that okay ?

Comment: no xml file created or content of xml file are invisible?

Comment: @navylover no xml file created only activity.xml is getting created

Comment: Jason, Install All except NDK. Then it might work.

Comment: or fragment xml not created?

Comment: @navylover i didnt select "use fragments", i wanted content xml to be created

Comment: :( @UmangBurman dont know what happened for the initial activity it created, but for additional it is not creating with the current tools only

Comment: Don't get stressed, There might be some small issue, Which OS are you using?

Comment: @UmangBurman, windows

Comment: and it is not displaying the app bar for newly created activities

Comment: Is there any error or something? You mean Java files are not creating right? Which is the latest SDK you have installed now in your SDK manager?

Comment: @UmangBurman everything is working fine and i am able to simulate the app in emulater as well, only thing is content xml is not getting generated and app bar is not getting displayed

Comment: You may want to re-install AS and try in that case, because my Content xml and app bar both are showing.. in a Basic Activity. I created it just now again. For you.

Answer (score 1):

Empty activity default contains only a single layout file

Read this 
[Activity template](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates)

> This template creates an empty activity and a single layout file with sample text content. It allows you to start from scratch when building your app module or activity.

But you can create  the content layout separately then include into the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of Android Studio, activity_main.xml will affect how global UI of Activity is designed and works. But content_main.xml will affect the contents in the activity_main.xml.

Since a Basic Activity,Empty Activity doesn't have much content, thus the **content_main.xml is not created for those**. If you create a Navigation Drawer Activity, Studio will create both `app_bar_main.xml` , `content_main.xml` and `activity_main.xml`

Comment: No use for Navigation drawer it is creating fragment.xml :(

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, the activity_main xml file created by wizard is the **content** xml file when create Basic Activity.
Then you could modify the activity_main xml to fulfil your requirment.